# App crashes when i use Cursor method to get data from SQlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

This is my code, the `Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery` is the reason. My app keep crashing

please tell me what's wrong:-

```
public QuestionController(Context context) {
    dbHelper= new DBHelper(context);
}

//Lấy danh sách câu hỏi
public ArrayList<Question> getQuestion(int num_exam, String subject){
    ArrayList<Question> lsData= new ArrayList<Question>();
    SQLiteDatabase db= dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tracnghiem WHERE num_exam = '"+ num_exam+"' AND subject='"+subject+"' ORDER BY random()",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Question item;
        item= new Question(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getInt(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),"");
        lsData.add(item);
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
    return lsData;
```

Comment: Please share your LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure But You Can Try these,

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tracnghiem WHERE num_exam = ? AND subject=? ORDER BY random()", new String[] {num_exam,subject});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that it is definitely the issue, but **you should not assume that the Cursor is not empty by not checking the result of the `moveToFirst` method**. That is `moveToFist` will return false if the move cannot be made e.g. if the Cursor is empty.

If the cursor is empty the `moveToFist` will not fail BUT an attempt to retrieve data via a `get????` method will then fail with a row index error as you are attempting to access row 0 of the cursor when there isn't a row 0.

Again not that it is definitely the error you are experiencing. However you should replace :-

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
    Question item;
    item= new Question(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getInt(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),"");
    lsData.add(item);
}while (cursor.moveToNext());
cursor.close();
```

with something like *(this will loop through the cursor if it is not empty, and not fail if the cursor is empty)* :-

```
while (cursor.moveToNext) {
    Question item;
    item= new Question(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getInt(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),"");
    lsData.add(item);
}
cursor.close();
```

Noting that lsData will have no elements should the Cursor itself be empty. You could add something, after `cursor.close()` and before `return lsData` along the lines of :-

```
if (lsData.size) < 1) {
    lsData.add(new Question(0,"Empty Cursor","","","","","",0,"".""."");
}
```

It could then be easy to see if the Cursor was empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in this line , Before line `cursor.moveToFirst();` check one condition.

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       //your process for fetching row.
   }
}
```

Comment: `cursor!=null` is needless as a cursor, at least from SQLiteDatabase methods, is never null.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there can be only 3 leaks for crashing app,

- Established connection with DB is not proper.
- Wrong query (table or fields in table not exist in DB).
- Your `cursor` returns 0 rows.

Comment: A returned Cursor, at least from SQLiteDatabase methods, is never null, if there is no data extracted then an empty valid cursor is returned.

Comment: You are right. Thanks